# How to edit current command in terminal with some editor?

Tags: command-line, bash

Let a long command in a default ubuntu terminal (`gnome-terminal`?). I need to edit this command in some editor (`vim`?) and run. So, I can copy the current line to the clipboard, start `vim`, insert the command to it, edit the command, copy it to the clipboard and paste it to the terminal prompt and run. Is there a simpler way to edit the current command with some editor?

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in line editor in bash. You find previous command lines with the 'arrow up' button (can be repeated). You edit with the normal method (arrow left and right to move the cursor), backspace and del to delete characters, type letters etc.

-o-

After closing a terminal window, the previous commands are stored in the file ~/.bash_history. You can edit it with any editor, for example gedit, (or in text mode with nano or vim).

```
gedit ~/.bash_history
```